# Check if a user visited a page?

Tags: javascript

I don't think this is possible, but perhaps someone knows of a way. I know Gleam.io is doing something similar, so maybe there is a way.

I have a button that if you click it, it opens somesite.com. The user clicks a button and I open this page with javascript. The problem is, after clicking the button, I want to know for sure the user opened the page. Maybe even go as far as making sure he scrolled to the bottom.

Is this in any way possible? Keeping mind that the target URL can vary.

Comment: Not if you don’t have any control over the target site.

Comment: Not possible unless you control the target page enough to run scripts on it

Comment: So any gander as to how Gleam does it? They probably just assume someone viewed it after clicking on their link... even if an adblocker stops it etc...

Comment: Websites integrating with such Apps usually import their library in their website. 

Which means once the website does open, their imported library identifies the credentials and reports it as valid or invalid. This is how most of the attribution is done.

Comment: Gleam requires that their JavaScript widget is installed in the target page, if they do any specific tracking. You can't track the user's actions in arbitrary web sites. That would lead to horrendous security/privacy issues.

Answer (score -2):

You can user 'mixpanel.com' for track the user and also put a scroll event with particular width and add that user in database or use any platform like 'mixpanel' for track the user.